# Is there any performance difference between for() and while()?

Tags: c++, c, performance, for-loop, while-loop

Or is it all about semantics?

Comment: Any particular reason you couldn't have written a couple of small benchmarks and tested this for yourself?

Comment: @Neil: Because there might be obscure cases where it does make a real difference, and a couple of small benchmarks wouldn't test those cases.

Comment: What about making a benchmark exactly for those obscure cases?

Comment: @Cătălin - I think the key word in RichieHindle's comment is *might*. I imagine the OP was hoping some people here might not know what those cases would be.

Comment: @Richie - So rather than get some objective figures, it's better to go for a straw poll of a few SO users, all of whom are using weasle words like "probably" and "may"? Not the approach I'd take if I really cared about the answer.

Comment: You still need to know what such cases might be before you can write a benchmark to measure them.

Comment: @Neil: No, I'll give you five reasons - 1) I'm not skilled when it comes to benchmarking. I'd make 5 million iterations, and I wouldn't trust the result. 2) I don't know if there are narrow cases where it might be different even if a simple bm shows identical clocks. 3) I need the answer faster than I can get to a compiler. 4) To improve the SO database range of questions/answers. 5) To gain a thousand new rep points... honestly I see you downvoting and close-voting all over the place. Please drop it.

Comment: @Neil: The question is a good one.  Maybe R.A is being a bit lazy, but so what?  It does improve the question base in SO.

Comment: I can't believe the number of answers here that give "an opinion" on a question that will have a definite answer. Also R.A I'd remove "noteworthy" from the question title, each programmers definition of noteworthy may/will differ greatly. There either is a difference or there is not

Comment: @Neil: Even if R.A can write a loop to do 5 million iterations, he most likely won't hit the interesting cases where it does make a difference, because he doesn't know he should look for them.  Crowdsourcing the answer on SO can give ideas on how to test, if necessary.

Comment: @Nathan It would improve the question base if the anwers were not all opinions.

Comment: @Neil: Yes, I can write that loop, as I said, and I wouldn't trust the resulting benchmark.

Comment: @Neil: At the risk of appearing inflamitory, perhaps you could venture an answer to the question, as you appear very outspoken about it and the way it is being answered?

Comment: @xan I don't see a one-sentence SO comment as being "very outspoken".  My point is that there are some questions that anyone with an enquiring mind can and should answer for themselves.

Comment: @Neil, it's possible that an answer here will tell when it's not the same and give some insight.  It seems you have a problem with the answers.  Why "attack" the guy who asked the question?  You're right about the opinions, but a poor benchmark is worse than a poor opinion, because it gives the impression that it can be trusted.

Comment: you forgot about do{} while();

;-P

Comment: @nathan I sometimes think I am the only person on SO who owns a compiler! If someone posts a benchmark, then anyone can compile it, run it & pick holes in it. This is known as the scientific method. A poor opinion is much more difficult to detect.

Comment: Something tells me the amount of debate on subjects like this is in inverse ratio to how much it matters.

Comment: Just to say the obvious: Neither is faster than the other. Each can do the same job like the other and everything entirely depends on the compiler and the backend for each one.

Comment: Here would be a fun experiment ;-)  I wonder if the amount of debate would be multiplied by asking if it makes a difference if the first instruction of the loop falls on an odd or even byte boundary?

Comment: @Binary Worrier the question doesn't specify machine or compiler, so even if you do run a benchmark, it's still just an opinion that the result is general to whatever platform the OP is on.

Comment: It's a bad question.  It asks if there is some difference in general, when any difference will depend entirely on the compiler.  Nor is it a matter of "semantics"; it's usually a matter of syntax, which is something else entirely on the compiler level.

Comment: If you're considering choosing one loop style over another as a performance consideration, you're almost certainly over-optimizing.  The choice between while and for should be based solely on code readability, in all but the most extreme circumstances -- and in those cases, you should probably be writing assembly instead anyway.  This is a fun question to ask from an academic standpoint, but I hope to god no one is actually looking at this as a serious optimization possibility.

Comment: @Frank: I hope so to :). I actually asked the question because if you look at the other parts of C (not C++), the semantics are quite sparse. But then, when it comes to loops - three different constructs, which appearantly only differs in terms of syntax/semantics. It seemed odd to me. Still does.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Short answer: no, they are exactly the same.

Guess it could in theory depend on the compiler; a really broken one might do something slightly different but I'd be surprised.

Just for fun here are two variants that compile down to exactly the same assembly code for me using x86 gcc version 4.3.3 as shipped with Ubuntu. You can check the assembly produced on the final binary with [objdump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) on linux.

```
int main()
{
#if 1
    int i = 10;
    do { printf("%d\n", i); } while(--i);
#else
    int i = 10;
    for (; i; --i) printf("%d\n", i);
#endif
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is an "oranges with oranges" while loop example that also compiles down to the same thing:

```
    while(i) { printf("%d\n", i); --i; }
```

Comment: +1 for performing an experiment, and not just "expressing an opinion"

Comment: Another +1 for due diligence by performing an experiment.  Great answer!

Comment: -1 for comparing apples (for) to oranges (do-while) which in general are not equivalent. You should use the functionally equivalent while loop instead.

Comment: +1 for saying it really depends on the compiler. it compiles to exactly the same code with my eco32 gcc backend too (risc, very simple architecture) (gcc 4.4)

Comment: It should be "while", not "do-while".  Only the #else case tests "i" before the first printf.

Comment: @akent: This would be a great answer to front this question if you could update with the assembly output of both the gcc and vc6 compilers.

Comment: Even clang compiles down to the same IR code after optimization: http://codepad.org/4raok1fN , using this command: clang-cc -emit-llvm main.c -o - | llvm-as | opt -std-compile-opts | llvm-dis

Comment: @Shmoopty Hmm, possibly, but seems like GCC optimises that compare away. Another option is writing the while loop as: while(i) { printf("%d\n", i); --i; }  --- this too is identical to the other two cases.

Comment: @Binary Worrier: Many times, opinions expressed are results of past experiments and not just blind guesswork.

Comment: @Mehrdad: while that is true, it is not helpful on a site like this.  Providing an answer without evidence (or at least a description of how the asker can gather such evidence themselves) is of minimal value, and not much better than an unfounded opinion.

Answer (score 14):

If your for and while loops do the same things, the machine code generated by the compiler should be (nearly) the same.

For instance in some testing I did a few years ago,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
...
}
```

and

```
int i = 0;
do
{
  ...
  i++;
}
while (i < 10);
```

would generate exactly the same code, or (and Neil pointed out in the comments) with one extra jmp, which won't make a big enough difference in performance to worry about.

Comment: "should be": Have you any hard evidence to support your claim?

Comment: Actually, on my VC++ 6.0 compiler, they do not generate exactly the same code. The for() verrsion generates an extra jmp instruction.

Comment: @Neil: How about posting your experiment as an answer which can be reproduced.

Comment: Before people start getting excited, I should point out the jmp is only taken once, no matter how many iteration of the loop. My point was the code is not identical and that one should check these things empirically.

Comment: Why did you change the while to a do-while? It might be infinitestimally faster in some cases, but it will burn you in others.

Comment: I changed the while to a do-while because remembering back to the tests I made a few years ago, the for loop does a jmp to the test at the end.  I wish I was at home so I could generate the code and compare it directly rather than trying to remember it.

Answer (score 8):

There is no semantic difference, there need not be any compiled difference. But it depends on the compiler. So I tried with with g++ 4.3.2, CC 5.5, and xlc6.

**g++, CC were identical, xlc WAS NOT**

The difference in xlc was in the initial loop entry.

```
extern int doit( int );
void loop1( ) {
  for ( int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++ ) {
    doit( ii );
  }
}

void loop2() {
  int ii = 0; 
  while ( ii < 10 ) {
    doit( ii );
    ii++;
  }
}
```

**XLC OUTPUT**

```
.loop2:                                 # 0x00000000 (H.10.NO_SYMBOL)
    mfspr   r0,LR
    stu     SP,-80(SP)
    st      r0,88(SP)
    cal     r3,0(r0)
    st      r3,64(SP)
    l       r3,64(SP)  ### DIFFERENCE ###
    cmpi    0,r3,10
    bc      BO_IF_NOT,CR0_LT,__L40
...
enter code here
.loop1:                                 # 0x0000006c (H.10.NO_SYMBOL+0x6c)
    mfspr   r0,LR
    stu     SP,-80(SP)
    st      r0,88(SP)
    cal     r3,0(r0)
    cmpi    0,r3,10    ### DIFFERENCE ###
    st      r3,64(SP)
    bc      BO_IF_NOT,CR0_LT,__La8
...
```

Answer (score 7):

The scope of the variable in the test of the `while` loop is wider than the scope of variables declared in the header of the `for` loop.

Therefore, if there are performance implications as a side-effect of keeping a variable alive longer, then there will be performance implications in choosing between a while and a for loop ( and not wrapping the while up in {} to reduce the scope of its variables ).

An example might be a concurrent collection which counts the number of iterators referring to it, and if more than one iterator exists, it applies locking to prevent concurrent modification, but as an optimisation elides the locking if only one iterator refers to it. If you then had two `for` loops in a function using differently named iterators on the same container, the fast path would be taken, but with two `while` loops the slow path would be taken. Similarly there may be performance implications if the objects are large (more cache traffic), or use system resources. But I can't think of a real example that I've ever seen where it would make a difference.

Comment: I like "wrapping the while up in {} to reduce the scope of its variables."

Comment: But that assumes that the intent is to have the variable have a longer life.  The great thing about for() is that you have the option of declaring a variable whose scope is the life of the loop.  while() doesn't give you that option.

Answer (score 6):

Compilers that optimize using loop unrolling will probably only do so in the for-loop case.

Comment: Great point! Good insight that I think a lot of people forget about.  Optimization is an aspect that shouldn't be ignored.

Answer (score 5):

Both are equivalent.  It's a matter of semantics.

The only difference may lie in the do... while construct, where you postpone the evaluation of the condition until *after* the body, and thus may save 1 evaluation.

```
i = 1; do { ... i--; } while( i > 0 );
```

as opposed to

```
for(  i = 1; i > 0; --i )
{ ....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I write compilers.  We compile all "structured" control flow (`if`, `while`, `for`, `switch`, `do`...`while`) into conditional and unconditional branches.  Then we analyze the control-flow graph.  Since a C compiler has to deal with general `goto` anyway, it is easiest to reduce *everything* to branch and conditional-branch instructions, then be sure to handle that case well.  (A C compiler has to do a good job not just on handwritten code but also on automatically generated code, which may have many, many `goto` statements.)

Comment: + I also have written compilers and other code generators. Low-level optimization is a great subject for people who write compilers. For people who USE compilers, there are far bigger ways to influence the speed of code, mainly by avoiding over-design.

Comment: Yeah, but I do have a bit of a gripe with profiling. Only some of them actually sample the whole call stack, and I don't think any of them tell what percent of samples contain any given call site, which is exactly what the call site costs. They are more interested in functions than function calls, so you gotta rummage around in the function to find what needs fixing.

Comment: ... Some newer ones give stats at the statement level, but they're still hung up on the notions of counting execution and/or timing duration. You gotta multiply those and then divide by some total time, within an interval of interest, to start getting close to what matters.

Comment: ... They are also hung up on the ideas that 1) the stats have to have high precision, and 2) heaven forbid we should slow down the program.

Comment: @Mike: I am still waiting for a really good profiler.  The PC-sampling ones, like gprof, are OK, but what's fielded deals badly with recursion and virtual method calls.  There are things to like about cost-center profiling and about valgrind, but overall this is an area where I would love to see better tools and better minimum standards.

Comment: Right. This was my attempt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368831/how-to-write-a-profiler/738647#738647

Comment: ... and another link, inspired by looking at LukeStackwalker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368831/how-to-write-a-profiler/874632#874632

Comment: Dittos on writing compilers, though my last was a long time ago, and compiled to an interpreted language.  When trying to understand performance, and why these questions can be a bit pointless, it helps to understand how "advanced" control structures actually work, and how variables are bought on the stack during execution.

Answer (score 3):

No.  If they're doing equivalent things, they'll compile to the same code - as you say, it's about semantics.  Choose the one that best represents what you're trying to express.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally it should be the same, but eventually it depends on your compiler/interpreter. To be sure, you must measure or examine the generated assembly code.

Proof that there may be a difference: These lines produce different assembly code using cc65.

```
for (; i < 1000; ++i);   
while (i < 1000) ++i;
```

Answer (score 1):

On Atmel ATMega while() is faster than for(). Why is this is explained in AVR035: Efficient C Coding for AVR.

P.S. Original platform was not mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1):

**continue** behaves differently in **for** and **while**: in **for**, it alters the counter, in **while**, it usually doesn't

Comment: which counter are you talking about?

Comment: in the code below, i is a counter:

for ( i = 1; i < 10; ++i) { ... }

i = 1; while ( i < 10) { ... ; ++i }

Comment: There is no counter in a while() loop.  There is only the loop control expression.

Answer (score 1):

To add another answer: In my experience, optimizing software is like a big, bushy beard being shaved off a man.

- First you lop it off in big chunks with scissors (prune whole limbs off the call tree).
- Then you make it short with an electric clipper (tweak algorithms).
- Finally you shave it with a razor to get rid of the last little bit (low-level optimization).

The last is where the difference between `for()` and `while()` might, but probably won't, make a difference.

P.S. The programmers I know (who are all very good, and I suspect are a representative sample) basically go at it from the other direction.

Comment: I'd upvote your answer for the creative analogy (which is spot-on, btw), but this isn't BeardOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

They are the same as far as performance goes. I tend to use `while` when waiting for a state change (such as waiting for a buffer to be filled) and `for` when processing a number of discrete objects (such as going through each item in a collection).

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in some cases.

If you are at the point where that difference matters, you either need to pick a better algorithm or begin coding in assembly language. Trust me, coding in assembly is preferable to fixing your compiler version.

Answer (score 0):

Is `while()` faster/slower than `for()`?  Let's review a few things about optimization:

- Compiler-writers work very hard to shave cycles by having fewer calls to jump, compare, increment, and the other kinds of instructions that they generate.
- Call instructions, on the other hand, consume many magnitudes more cycles, but the compiler is nearly powerless to do anything to remove those.
- As programmers, we write lots of function calls, some because we mean to, some because we're lazy, and some because the compiler slips them in without being obvious.
- Most of the time, it doesn't matter, because the hardware is so fast, and our jobs are so small, that the computer is like a beagle dog who wolfes her food and begs for more.
- Sometimes, however, the job is big enough that performance is an issue.
- What do we do then? Where's the bigger payoff?

  - Getting the compiler to shave a few cycles off loops & such?
  - Finding function calls that don't *-really-* need to be done so much?
- The compiler can't do the latter. Only we the programmers can.
- We need to learn or be taught how to do this. It doesn't come naturally.
  We are congenitally inclined to make wrong guesses and then bet on them.
  Getting better algorithms is a start, but only a start. Our teachers need to teach this, if indeed *they* know how.
- Profilers are a start. [I do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)

The apocryphal quote of Willie Sutton when asked **Why do you rob banks?**:
**Because that's where the money is.**

If you want to save cycles, find out where they are.

Answer (score -4):

Probably only coding style.

- for if you know the number of iterations.
- while if you do not know the number of iterations.

Comment: Not all for() loops have a fixed, known, or knowable number of iterations.  The "test" expression can be anything, including a function call.  The "next" expression, likewise, can be just about anything as well.